# Codeigniter variable not found message in sub views

Tags: codeigniter

I have stacked with the situation , please anyone help me !

Controller ->

```
public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data ['tittle'] = 'Membership Payment';
    $data ['page'] = $this->load->view('membership_payment', $data, true);
    $data ['breadcrumb'] = $this->load->view('breadcrumb', $data, true);
    $data['result'] = $this->payment_model->membership_payment();
    $data['db']='---------------';
    $this->load->view('master', $data);
```

View->master page

```
<?php echo $db; ?>
```

Master pages working fine , but problem is i have subpages membership_payment , in this page the data array variable are not working ,

Display the variable not found , there is any trick to pass data array to master subpage

Thanks in Advance !

ROB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've used `$result` which is the returned data of `membership_payment();` method in the `membership_payment` view file.

If so, just **change the order** of the following line and put that over the `$data['page']`, as follows:

```php
// ...
$data['result'] = $this->payment_model->membership_payment();
$data ['page'] = $this->load->view('membership_payment', $data, true);
// ...
```

Comment: @ROBENGG You are welcome :) Since you are new to Stackoverflow, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as *accepted* by clicking the check mark.